# Number of arrangements of $4$ similar pots of roses and $3$ similar pots of lilies in which only two pots of lilies can be arranged next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

can anyone help to solve the problem below?

1. 4 similar pots of roses and 3 similar pots of lily are arranged in a row. Find the number of ways to arrange the flowers if only two pots of lily can be arranged next to each other.

My solution,

These 7 flowers have 8 "gaps". Lets arrange the pots (without a lily pot) , so we will have _ _ _ _ _ _ six pots with 7 gaps (to slip a lily pot into). So total arrangements are, 5!/(4!)= 5. And we can use only 4 gaps out of 7 gaps to slip a lily into (avoid grouping with the two lily pots). So 5*4=20, is this correct?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig You are right. I erase my previous remark.

Comment: A deflowered version of your problem : how many numbers with 7 digits (0/1) in binary system exist with 4 "zeros" (rOses) and 3 "ones" (1ilies) with two "ones" together ? (is three ones together permitted ? the question is not fully clear).

Comment: @JeanMarie  The way I read this is that at most two pots of lilies may be adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect.  You set aside one of the three lily pots, which leaves you with four pots of roses and two pots of lilies to arrange.  They can be arranged in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, not $\binom{5}{4}$.  Had you done this step correctly, you would have to consider two cases, depending on whether or not the two pots of lilies already placed are adjacent.

**Method 1:**  We subtract those arrangements in which all three lily pots are adjacent from the total number of arrangements.

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to arrange four pots of roses and three pots of lilies in a row.  If the three pots of lilies are adjacent, we have five objects to arrange:  R, R, R, R, LLL.  There are five ways to place the block of three lily pots among the four roses.  Hence, the number of arrangements of four pots of roses and three pots of lilies in which at most two pots of lilies are adjacent is
$$\binom{7}{3} - 5$$

**Method 2:**  We perform a direct count.

There are two cases to consider:

- no two pots of lilies are adjacent
- exactly two pots of lilies are adjacent

*No two pots of lilies are adjacent*:  Arrange the four pots of roses in a row.  This creates five spaces in which to place the pots of lilies, three between adjacent pots of roses and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square R \square R \square R \square R \square$$
To ensure that no two pots of lilies are adjacent, we must choose three of these five spaces in which to place a pot of lilies, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

*Exactly two pots of lilies are adjacent*:  Arrange the four pots of roses in a row.  Again, this creates five spaces in which to place the pots of lilies.  To ensure that exactly two pots of lilies are adjacent, choose one of these five spaces in which to place two pots of lilies and one of the remaining four spaces in which to place the remaining pot of lilies, which can be done in $5 \cdot 4$ ways.

Hence, there are
$$\binom{5}{3} + 5 \cdot 4$$
arrangements of four pots of roses and three pots of lilies in which at most two pots of lilies are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question :

first examples : inserting 2 lily pots ll

l r ll r r r ; l r r ll r r ; l r r rll r ; l r r r r ll   (4 cases)

ll r l r r r ; r l r ll r r ; r l r r ll r ; r l r r r ll (always 4 cases)

nb cases = 5 * 4 for l and ll are distinguishable

if lily pots are not necessarily forming a pair :

l r l r l r r ; l r l r r l r ; . . .

nb cases = 3 among 5 = (5 * 4 * 3)/(2 * 3)

for l, l, l are not distinguishable.